# Windows 10 and IPv6 link-local address

Tags: windows-10, networking, ipv6, link-local-address

As far as I know, IPv6 is calculated from the MAC Address (EUI-64 Method) and it is autoconfigured whether there is a DHCP or not.

So I enabled TCP/IPv6 on my Windows 10 and used `ipconfig /all`, but all I see is MAC and IPv4 related information and no link-local address at all.

So how is link-local address assigned to computer? Are there any further steps? Or is it not possible at all in my case?

Regards

Comment: I’d like to know too if Microsoft failed to implement the most useful feature of IPv6? Insane if so.